# Calculating errors in polynomial coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, polynomials

I currently have written some code that generates a polynomial to interpolate several data sets that I have. I am now wanting to calculate the error in the polynomial coefficients but am unsure about how to go about this.

My current code below:

```py
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = [0,5,16,18.5,30,50]
a = [1.41,1.43,0.72,0.78,0.8,0.86]
b = [3.80e-5,5.40e-5,5.14e-5,5.16e-5,8.5e-5,1.58e-4]
c = [1.6e-2,1.54e-2,10.523e-2,14.589e-2,11.1e-2,5.66e-2]

f_new = np.linspace(f[0], f[5], num=len(f)*10)

coefs_a = poly.polyfit(f, a, 3)
coefs_b = poly.polyfit(f, b, 2)
coefs_c = poly.polyfit(f, c, 2)

ffit_a = poly.polyval(f_new, coefs_a)
ffit_b = poly.polyval(f_new, coefs_b)
ffit_c = poly.polyval(f_new, coefs_c)

print(coefs_a)
print(coefs_b)
print(coefs_c)

plt.plot(f,a)
plt.show()

plt.plot(f_new, ffit_a)
plt.title('a')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Coefficient value')
plt.show()

plt.plot(f,b)
plt.show()

plt.plot(f_new, ffit_b)
plt.title('b')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Coefficient value)')
plt.show()

plt.plot(f,c)
plt.show()

plt.plot(f_new, ffit_c)
plt.title('c')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Coefficient value')
plt.show()
```

So currently, I generate coefficient values and therefore polynomials for the quantities named ''a'', ''b'' and ''c'' and now want to get the errors in these coefficients so I can calculate an overall error for each of the ''a'', ''b'' and ''c'' quantities.

Comment: please format the code in a code block with triple backticks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of squared residuals (a measure of error) for each fit if you set `full=True`

eg in your code to get the residuals for `coefs_a`,

```
coefs_a, res_a = poly.polyfit(f, a, 3, full=True)
print(res_a[0]) # res_a will be a list with the 1st entry being the sum of residuals
```

Docs for [numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html)